# How to use mock implementation in Google cloud functions integration test

Tags: google-cloud-functions, integration-testing, google-cloud-pubsub, functions-framework

I am using google cloud function written in javascript to do the transformation of an event received from a pub/sub topic and publishing it to another pub/sub topic.
Function is working perfectly fine. My question is around testing.

I have been following googles guide to write unit and integration tests.
Unit tests are working fine. I am using Jest framework.
I am not sure how to complete Integration tests.
I am following [this](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/testing/test-background#integration_tests) link
Cloud function is publishing to another topic at the end. How do I test this integration test.
I am using [functions-framework](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs) as suggested by google to do the integration test.
Does anyone have any idea how do I inject mock implementation for pub/sub publishing part

Integration test looks similar to [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/functions/helloworld/test/sample.integration.pubsub.test.js)